# How do I redirect by URL pattern in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a Django based website. I would like to redirect URLs with the pattern `servertest` in them to the same URL except `servertest` should be replaced by `server-test`.

So for example the following URLs would be mapped be redirected as shown below:

```
http://acme.com/servertest/                        =>  http://acme.com/server-test/ 

http://acme.com/servertest/www.example.com         =>  http://acme.com/server-test/www.example.com

http://acme.com/servertest/www.example.com:8833    =>  http://acme.com/server-test/www.example.com:8833
```

I can get the first example working using the following line in urls.py:

```py
    ('^servertest/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/'}),
```

Not sure how to do it for the others so only the servetest part of the URL is replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following (updated for Django 2.2):

```
re_path(r'^servertest/(?P<path>.*)$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/%(path)s'}),
```

It takes zero or more characters after `servertest/` and places them after `/server-test/`.

Alternatively, you can use new `path` function that covers simple cases url patterns without using regex (and it is preferred in new versions of Django):

```
path('servertest/<path:path>', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/%(path)s'}),
```

Comment: aren't you missing `url()` - django says: `Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances. HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.`

Answer (score 7):

[It's covered in the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to)

> The given URL may contain dictionary-style string formatting, which will be interpolated against the parameters captured in the URL. Because **keyword interpolation is *always* done** (even if no arguments are passed in), any "%" characters in the URL must be written as "%%" so that Python will convert them to a single percent sign on output.

(Strong emphasis mine.)

And then their examples:

> This example issues a permanent redirect (HTTP status code 301) from
>   /foo/<id>/ to /bar/<id>/:
>
> ```
> from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>     ('^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/bar/%(id)s/'}),
> )
> ```

And so you see that it's just the nice straightforward form:

```
('^servertest/(?P<path>.*)$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/%(path)s'}),
```

Comment: Before your edit I got this error: "redirect_to() got multiple values for keyword argument 'url'" so I tried the answer from Simeon Visser which worked.

Comment: @TonyM: yeah, you can't use unnamed groups; they've got to be named. (I found that when I checked the source code, it's just `**kwargs`, not `*args`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression :

```
   ('^servertest/', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/'}),
```

or this one:
        ('^servertest', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/server-test/'}),