# How to rewrite base url in django to add logged in username in the url of all pages instead of app name?

Tags: django, python-2.7, url-rewriting

I am working on django application and I have base url of application as below:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/myblog/page
```

where **127.0.0.1:8000** is base url and **myblog** is App name and **page** is page name. 
So my requirement is to change the url to something like this without changing the internal code of my application:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/username/page
```

Basically I want to change App name with user name in the URL.
I have tried the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923178/how-do-i-rewrite-this-url-in-django) SO question. But it didn't helped much.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/urls/ You will be able to get the URL params in your view. You can take it from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass username into `url` regexp args and get request user from `request` class:
view:

```
def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExists:
        raise Http404
    # or use shortcut get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    if request.user.username != user.username:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'templates/user_template', {'user':user})
```

urls:

```
url(r'^(?<username>\w+)/page/$', views.user_page, name='user_page')
```

Note: `username` field not valid choice, if it not unique, it will produce an error when you get more then one user from `User.objects.get()`.  Better use `pk` field for user page lookup.

But there is simpler way for building user page for request user. Just one url without keyword arguments, which response data for authenticated user:

view:

```
def user_page(request):
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    return render(request, 'templates/user_template', {'user': user} )
```

urls:

```
url(r'^page/$', views.user_page, name='user_page')
```

Now it return data based on request user or `None` if user is not authenticated