# Regular expression for two alphabetical names concatinating by dot (.)

Tags: regex, django, url-rewriting

I need regular expression for something like:
abc.xyz (firstname.lastname) 
I have tried `[a-zA-Z ]*$\.[a-zA-Z ]*$` but it does not work.

**Update**

My actual requirement is to add user's firstname.lastname in url to get something like:

www.abc.com/simer.pqr/profile

This I have to do for django(python) project. Therefore need regular expression.

*For the exact requirement I have posted another question [SO question - rewrite django url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781442/how-to-rewrite-base-url-in-django-to-add-logged-in-username-in-the-url-of-all-pa)*

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Comment: Why using `$` (end of line)? Remove them and replace `*` with `+`: `[a-zA-Z ]+\.[a-zA-Z ]+`. Or better `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*`.

Comment: Do you need to validate or extract? Did the expression above work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to write rule for url. It unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`$` means end of string, so you should not use it inside your string.

Your URL regexp should look like `^(P?<fname>[^.]+)\.(?P<lname>[^/]+)/profile$`