# Django: how to send argument in HtpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from  django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from  django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from .models import studentDetails
from .forms import loginForm

# Create your views here.


def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, "login.html", c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get("username", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")

    q = studentDetails.objects.get(name=username)

    if q.password==password:
        return  HttpResponseRedirect("/student/accounts/loggedin")

    return  HttpResponseRedirect("/studemt/accounts/invalid")



def loggedin(request):
    username = request.GET.get("username")
    return  render(request, "loggedin.html", {"full_name": username})


def invalid(request):
    return  render(request, "invalid_login.html")


def logout(request):
    return  render(request, "logout.html")
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (
    login,
    auth_view,
    loggedin,
    logout
    )


urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^accounts/login/$", login ,  name="login"),
    url(r"^accounts/auth/$", auth_view ,name="auth_view"),
    url(r"^accounts/loggedin/$", loggedin , name="loggedin"),
    url(r"^accounts/logout/$", logout, name="logout"),

]
```

i want to send username from auth_view to loggedin view but i don'y know how to do that.
 i have used `username = request.GET.get("username")` but it is not working.
i want to show username in url also such that it looks like `/student/username/`
where username will change as different user login.

Comment: **"where username will change as different user login"** I think, my answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781442/how-to-rewrite-base-url-in-django-to-add-logged-in-username-in-the-url-of-all-pa/38895767#38895767

Comment: in my quesion auth_view is not rendering any page it is simply checking data and it want to send username from auth_view to loggedin view.

Comment: You would usually store that in a [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/).  Or use [djangos auth system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: can you tell me how to store session?

Comment: @RohitChopra - you should read the [link] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) I've pointed to. [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_sessions.htm) also seems decent.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameter in url first:

```
url(r'^student/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.userpage, name='userpage)
```

But better use `pk` field or something with `name` + `pk`, as url parametr, because username can be duplicate.
Now you can pass this parameter in view and don't hardcore url, use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/) with url name instead.

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get("username", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")

    q = studentDetails.objects.get(name=username)

    if q.password==password:
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('userpage', args=[q.username]))

    return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('invalid'))
```

Comment: i have change view and urls accordingly but it is not working **error:** `Reverse for 'loggedin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
`  **change url :** `url(r'^(?P<username>)/$', loggedin, name='loggedin'),` **change views.py** `def auth_view(request):
 username = request.POST.get("username", "")
 password = request.POST.get("password", "")
 q = studentDetails.objects.get(name=username)
 if q.password==password:
  return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loggedin'), args=[q.username])
 return  HttpResponseRedirect("/studemt/accounts/invalid")`

Comment: ah yes, there was typo in `reverse` function, `args` must locate in `reverse`

Comment: what traceback sayed?

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /student/accounts/auth/
Reverse for 'loggedin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'arun'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: seems you use old url `/student/accounts/auth/ ` instead of  `url(r'^(?P<username>)/$` Also in previous traceback you forgot `\w+` regexp pointer. It should looks like this `url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$`

Comment: urls.py
`urlpatterns = [ url(r"^accounts/login/$", login ,  name="login"), url(r"^accounts/auth/$", auth_view ,name="auth_view"),
   
    url(r"^accounts/logout/$", logout, name="logout"),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', loggedin, name='loggedin'),
]`  **views.py**  `def auth_view(request):
 username = request.POST.get("username", "")
 password = request.POST.get("password", "")
 q = studentDetails.objects.get(name=username)
 if q.password==password:
  return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loggedin', kwargs={"username": username}))
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121452/discussion-between-baterson-and-rohit-chopra).